# Bind WPF TextBox to Entity object

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, entity

I want to bind `TextBox.Text` property in my WFP application to EF entity object's property.

Here is the entity object initialization:

```
public static Question CurrentQuestion = new Question
       {
             Description = "How old are you?"
       };
```

And here is the function to databind textbox:

```
private void BindQuestionControls()
        {
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.Source = CurrentQuestion;
            b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            b.Path = new PropertyPath("Description");
            textBoxQuestion.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
        }
```

I expect when app start then textBoxQuestion would display "How old are you?" but it is empty, possible it is better to set binding in declaration please suggest how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if you made a typo but at the set binding line you have to use TextBox.TextProperty not TextBlock.TextProperty.

Then this code works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be not

```
textBoxQuestion.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
```

but

```
textBoxQuestion.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```